# How to redirect information from one text file to another

Tags: ruby

What's the best way to take a line of text with a given piece of string from one text file and send it to another?

Currently have this:

```
def redirect_file
    File.readlines('file_name.txt') do |line|
        case test
        when line.include?("my_string_phrase")
            <Want to send the line(s) with my_string_phrase to a separate document>
        when line.include?("my_string_phrase2")
            <Want to send the line(s) with my_string_phrase2 to a separate document>
    end
end
```

EDIT: Needed a case statement instead, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I will write this code using [`::foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-foreach) and [`::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-open) methods.

```
def redirect_file(input_file, output_file)
  File.open(output_file, 'wb') do |file|
    File.foreach(input_file) do |line|
      if line.include?("my_string_phrase")
        file.puts line
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I ended up needing a case statement instead, but I really like this method of doing it, is there a work around for if  you require more than one document to receive different types of strings?

Comment: @user3850868 don't get you

Answer (score 1):

```
def redirect_file
  file1 = File.open('file1.txt', 'w')

  File.readlines('file_name.txt') do |line|
    if line.include?("my_string_phrase")
      file1.puts line
    end
  end

  file1.close
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit hackish but, open the file to write outside of the file to read then use both.

```
File.open("test.txt", "w+") do |f|
  File.readlines('file_name.txt') do |line|
    if line.include?("my_string_phrase")
      F.puts(line)
  end
end
```

Another option would be to build an array of lines you want to read then write them in a separate block that way it is a bit cleaner and more reusable.  It has the drawback of using more memory though.

```
  a = Array.new
  File.readlines('file_name.txt') do |line|
    if line.include?("my_string_phrase")
      a.push(line)
  end
  File.open("test.txt", "w+") do |f|
     a.each{ |i| f.puts(i)}
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the target file and write the selected lines to it.  Something along these lines should work:

```
def redirect_file
    File.open('destination.txt', 'w+') do |dest|
        File.readlines('file_name.txt') do |line|
            dest.write(line) if line.include?("my_string_phrase")
        end
    end
end
```

Do note, by the way, the the usual meaning of the the word "redirect" in an I/O context is somewhat different than what you asked about.